# Запрет создания базового класса

Tags: c++

Как запретить создание непосредственно экземпляров базового класса? Т.е. так, чтобы можно было создавать производные классы, а отдельно базовый - нет. Я делаю так:

```
class A
{
protected:
  A() {}
}
class B: public A
{
  B():A() {}
}
```

Будет ли ожидаемое поведение?

Comment: А абстрактный класс это не то?

Comment: @splash58 возможно, но хотелось бы без виртуальных функций

Comment: @splash58 т.е. для чего мне писать лишние виртуальные функции в базовом классе, которые не несут нагрузки? Проще написать один `protected` конструктор, чем 10 пустых функций

Comment: а чем они вам не угодили, если не секрет?

Comment: зачем, 10 не надо. достаточно одной. во вторых, я не пишу сто лет, но возможно тот же конструктор можно объявить виртуальной функией

Comment: @splash58 1) теоретически да, но интерфейс будет непонятен, если у нас 1 функция из 10 есть в базовом классе, а остальные 9 почему-то отсутствуют; 2) http://cpp-reference.ru/articles/virtual-constructor/

Comment: почему отсутствуют? - остальные обычные

Comment: @splash58 эти 10 функций есть только в производных классах, в базовом они не нужны. А для тех, которые наследуются, мне нужна реализация в базовом классе

Comment: @btws А кто мешает сделать реализацию чисто виртуальной функции? Насколько я помню, стандартом это не запрещено...

Comment: @Harry, а зачем добавлять виртуальность, когда она не нужна? Она ведь не бесплатна.

Comment: @ixSci Это второй вопрос :) Я просто ответил на конкретный вопрос - "*А для тех, которые наследуются, мне нужна реализация в базовом классе*", не более того.

Answer (score 5):

Если все конструкторы базового класса будут в `protected`/`private` секциях, тогда объект такого класса сможет создать только класс-наследник, либо же сущность-друг, более никто. Поэтому, ответ на Ваш вопрос — да, поведение будет ожидаемым.

Со своей стороны, хочется дать небольшой совет: Вы, в следующий раз, просто попробуйте скомпилировать код, тогда и вопрос задавать не придётся.

Answer (score 1):

Слышали когда-нибудь про абстрактные классы? Это как раз к вашему случае. Создаете любую чисто виртуальную функцию в классе A, чтобы сделать его абстрактным (нельзя будет создавать его собственные экземпляры, только классов-наследников)

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]